# Why did Django come to Candieland?

Tags: plot-explanation, django-unchained

I'm not sure it's ever explicitly explained why Schultz brings Django to Candieland in the first place?

Surely they were aware that their plan is greatly jeopardized by bringing Django along: not only does he have to temper his emotions around Broomhilda, they are also counting on Broomhilda being able to do the same with *no prior warning*.

Django has already fulfilled his purpose in proving to Candie that Schultz is interested in Mandigo fighting at the Cleopatra Club, which is how Schultz obtained his entry to Candieland. This proves Django was no longer needed *to convince Candie*.

Schultz was already very capable of handling himself, being a bounty hunter.

[image]

And as for 'back-up', surely the last possible thing the pair wanted was a Gunfight, so why anticipate one? It only happens due to the failure of their original plan.

[image]

And as for being able to positively identify Broomhilda, the dialogue already mentions that the chances of there being **two** African slaves named 'Broomhilda' are almost zero.

As far as I can see, the only thing that would jeopardize the plan is Django's presence, so why does he come along?

Edit: No 'because it makes the plot better' answers, please ;P. I know its a great movie, but I'm looking to see if this is explained within the movie.

Comment: not entirely sure but Candie wants both of them to accompany him to come to that place.

Comment: I don't think so, Candie is somewhat troubled at Schultz's insistence that the two come as partners: "You do the Bill foldin' and he does the eye ballin', is that correct?"

Comment: Are those pictures really necessary to provide any additional information or context or are they merely "beautifying" the question?

Comment: They're improving the aesthetic with relevant imagery to remind readers. Problem?

Comment: Well, they stretch the question with completely irrelevant stuff. Your explanations have already reminded the reader, seeing a guy shoot a gun and some guys lying around, well. But nevermind, I'll not edit them out anyway if you deem them necessary. I certainly don't want to rob the question of its *"intrigue"* either. ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau they're not *neccesary*, but they break up blocks of text and make reading more interesting for readers. I know you're aware of my feelings on dogmatic standardization ;)

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional: Merely a suggestion; but the readability of the question would increase dramatically if those images are removed. And you can always use proper formatting to break up large blocks of text.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional you know what you get when you standardize dogs right?

Answer (score 14):

I don't think it was ever even considered that Schultz goes there alone, so it's not an addressed issue. The rest of my answer is speculative.

First, it's Django's wife, so it is a matter of ego, and it is emotionally very important that he comes to her rescue. Given his temper, I have hard time imagining him waiting for Schultz to rescue her, even if it would be wise (which it probably would be).

Imagine, for a moment, the scenario in which Django waits somewhere while Schultz goes to Candieland. I think we can say, with absolute certainty, that he'd do something stupid, like go "see what's going on or if his help is needed". In a way, maybe it was reasonable for Schultz to want to keep an eye on Django.

Second, as you said, "the last possible thing the pair wanted was a gunfight", but -- and I quote another movie -- *want doesn't get*, so it is not unreasonable to anticipate a fight. However, you are right that Django greatly increased the possibility of a fight. And let's not forget that the fight was actually incited by Schultz, not by Django, so he too is a bit of a loose cannon (and most likely aware of that).

Third, this is South in the time of slavery. Separating Django from Schultz for a few days is risky, as there is a hunting season on masterless black men there. No formal papers would help him if a group of gun-happy white men came along his way, and his aforementioned temper wouldn't help diffuse the potential situation. So, leaving Django somewhere would impose a risk of Schultz losing an associate (and, I dare say, a friend), while getting his wife instead.

You are somewhat wrong about them "also counting on Broomhilde being able to do the same with *no prior warning*". That warning came in the room scene, where Schultz first to met her, and (tried to) prepare her for a meeting with Django.

It was actually a good plan, which would go all right if Candie didn't have Stephen who noticed Broomhilda's emotions. Who there, other than a very observant black men eager to please his master, would pay attention to emotions of a black woman?

Comment: Good answer +1. Although: it is still *Django*'s fault the ruse is revealed, or more specifically Django's reaction to Broomhilde being stripped, he is unable to control himself emotionally. Also, I think there would have been plausible hospitable places they could have left Django: Sheriff 'Snowy Snow' for one seems friendly enough to Django, for one. And I'm not sure about your speculation that we can say with *any* certainty, that Django would do something reckless.. he's done exactly as instructed by Schultz prior to this, as his mentor. Good attempt, though... :)

Comment: Maybe I misremember: wasn't it Broomhilde's reactions that made Stephen suspicious, after which it was easy to see through Schultz' and Django's game? Regardless of who revealed them, Schultz was the one to start a gunfight (discussed in [this answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/9047/5589)). As for Django doing something reckless, yes, my statement is a stretch, but I was referring to what usually happens in the movies. A character cannot have a smooth ride, so if their plan is good, they have to do something stupid. A movie director can only choose which stupid thing is more plausible.

Comment: Well yes, *of course* Schultz shot first, that was never under any question, this isn't A New Hope! by saying it 'was Django's fault the ruse is revealed', I'm referring to the fact it was his presence which ultimately exposed their true intentions. I think it was ultimately Djangos composure around Broomhilda (or vice-versa, doesnt matter) that exposed them, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: It's been a while since I've watched it. I think it was her looks towards Django that made Stephen very suspicious at first, but this was probably also helped by the scene when they take her out of the cage, right after Schultz and Django arrived to Candie's house. And yes, Django's obviously forced composure did attribute to Stephen's conclusion.

Comment: Either way, I think we can both agree that if Django wasn't there, Steven wouldn't have had anything to base his suspicions on....

Comment: Yes, we do. As I said in my answer: it would have probably been wise for Django to stay away. But then Tarantino would have a hell of a time trying to figure out how to kill almost everyone. ;-)

Comment: I think it was Broomhilda's reaction which completely gave their plan away and then Stephen's continuous suspicion on her. Point to note is that Candie was almost about to agree to Schultz's plan initially if not for Stephen's intervention!

Comment: But if he did not have Djnago how would he have been convincing as a mandigo fight enthusiast?

Comment: @Stefan Maybe he could have gone with some other plan. All he needed was a good excuse to go visit Candie and he'd be offered Broomhilda just like he was. Mandigo cover had nothing to do with that. Maybe there was no better plan, but that was never discussed, so they don't know there isn't one. They started and just went on with this one.

Comment: Ah, okay I see your point.  Django was an asset to the plan they showed but they could have used a different plan which did not require Django?

Comment: @Stefan Yes. That would remove the emotional component, but also Django's support. We can only hypothesize what would make a better plan. Mistah suggested a simple "Hi, I heard you have a German speaking slave and would like to purchase her" and I see no problem with that (especially if sugar coated to appeal to Candie's ego). Of course, that wouldn't make such an interesting movie, but that's not the point here.

Comment: I though they cover that particular plan? ISTR Schultz tells Django that if he tried to buy the slave girl Candie would, most likely, refuse to even speak to him or charge him a huge amount (although it has been a while since I watched it).  He needed some way of attracting Candie's interest and gaining a position from which to deal hence the story about being a fellow fight enthusiast?  Maybe he could not think of another angle to play to gain Candie's interest?

Comment: @Stefan The argument was something like "if I come and I want to buy this specific slave, Candie would become suspicious and overcharge me". However, "I heard you have a German speaking slave. Is it true and, if so, would you be interested in selling?" seems good. As I wrote before, we can speculate now as much as we like, but they never considered any alternatives in the movie.

Answer (score 5):

I'll take a different tack and state what may be obvious: It's a conceit of the narrative that Django goes along. He's the protagonist of the film, so his involvement in all aspects of that narrative becomes necessary to keep him in that role.

The film makes it abundantly clear that Candie's primary interest was in Mandingo fighting slaves. The remainder of his slaves (with the exception of his *majordomo* Joseph) serve little purpose to him and thus the narrative. This could be extended to Broomhilda, who we see is actually locked in a punishment sweatbox when Django and Schulz arrive at the Candieland plantation.

There is no reason for Django to go, as Schulz could have easily gone to the plantation seeking a female German-speaking slave. Since she was a "problem" for Candie's household and since his interests lied elsewhere (slaves bred for combat) it takes an exceptional stretch of the imagination to believe that he wouldn't not have sold her without much bargaining simply to be rid of her.

As for Django's not being "safe" without Schulz: There was an extensive slavery abolition movement in the US which peaked just prior to the Civil War. While fugitive slave raids did occur, they were rare in the far North and they were illegal in Canada. It would have been very easy in an era where identification documentation did not require photos for Schulz to take Django to a state or country where he would be beyond reach of any group seeking to enslave him again.

He could have then proceeded to Candieland, purchased Broomhilda, granted her freedom and then traveled with her to where Django was waiting for them. This plan would have placed none of them in danger (Why would Candie suspect an ulterior motive or even care?) it would have allowed them to save money as Candie would have rid himself of a "troubled slave" for a relative pittance and it might have made Django even more beholding to Schulz as he would have helped him free his beloved wife.

Instead, using rather convoluted plot logic, the film requires that the protagonist (Django) risk his life, it ends Schulz's life when he decides to murder Candie and then not provide an adequate plan which would have allowed Django and Broomhilda any method to escape. And finally, it risked Broomhilda's life,  as it would have simply been wiser to kill her and Django after Candie's murder if for no other reason than to make them examples for the other slaves who might have been considering similar actions.

While this is not a plot hole (it is consistent with the internal "logic" of narrative) it is certainly an unrealistic plot contrivance which is so glaring that it throws a thinking filmgoer out the sense of disbelief they require to make a film's fictional narrative seem to be realistic."

Comment: Thanks, Mistah Mix. I was hoping somewhere in the film there was a reason why Django *had* to go, because I agree with you entirely (and I suspect Vedran Šego does also) in your evaluation. It just seemed unnecessary, and primed for one of those "how it should have ended" parody videos. I do *Hate* answers that are just 'because that's what happens in the plot' but in your case I'm willing to make an exception because I think you're totally right.

Comment: Apart from Django's emotional reasons, I do agree with this. Schultz, when first explaining his plan to Django, says that Candie would be suspicious if he just went to buy Broomhilda, and this is the explanation for his overly complex plan. However, I am not that convinced that Candie would be suspicious (or even care), had it be presented, as Mistah Mix said, "I want a German speaking slave" instead of "I want this guy's wife". Btw, I am not so sure about the abolition part (in the movie universe). See how white people look at Django on the horse, or anywhere he goes with Schultz.

Comment: Those are White Americans in the slave-holding South. The abolition movement was in the Northern US and surprisingly played a much smaller role in the film than it did in reality. Uncle Tom's Cabin was the best-selling book in the US with the exception of the Bible prior to the Civil War and it was used by the abolitionist movement to combat slavery.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it was explained as to why Django went to Candieland.  Shultz was the money man in their little plan, while Django was the one who had to identify the fighter they intended to purchase.  Shultz explained this beforehand.  In their plan, Django was to play the part of the experienced and expert fighter, and thus the best judge of the fighter they were to purchase.

Yes, Django proved that Shultz had an interest in purchasing a Mandigo fighter, but that was all.  In that same scene, both Shultz and Django proved that Shultz had the money while Django was going to decide who the money would be spent on.  Since the fighter was at Candieland, Django had to go along to see for himself if the fighter was indeed the third best, and worth the $12k.

It is possible that they could have devised a different plan, where Shultz would not need Django at all, but it would have been far more difficult to pull off.  It would have been very easy for Shultz to make a mistake and prove he was no judge of fighters.  Moreover, with Django there, he was free to play a much more convincing part as just a rich and bored man looking to spend his money on more exciting matters.

Neither of them was counting on Stephen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bon, but I can't help but think you're missing the point of the question. We're aware of *the alibi* Schultz and Django created, we're discussing the details of their actual plan, not the way they present themselves to Candie. 'but it would have been far more difficult to pull off'...why do you believe it would have been so? 'easy for Shultz to make a mistake and prove he was no judge of fighters' I thought Schultz wasn't *supposed* to be a judge of fighters? If I were Candie, I'd have been much happier to take a 'gullible' Schultz without his intimidating bodyguard...

Comment: +1 OP starts question with "I'm not sure it's ever explained" and this answer clearly shows that it is explained, and provides the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was partially Django's character.

He wanted and probably felt it was approriate to help rescue his wife rather than let someone else do it and just sit on his hands.  Whilst his being there made things more complicated it was only an amazingly sharp witted Stephen who saw through anything.

He was desperate to see his wife again and wanted to either see her or find out what had happened to her as soon as humanly possible.

But also:

The bluff involved pretending to be on the lookout for Mandigo fighters.  If Shultz was to be plausible as a purchaser then he either needed to know about Mandigo fighters or have someone with him who did.  Django was a good candidate because, being as he was black, the chance of anyone engaging him in small talk and his lack of knowledge being exposed was minimal.  If anyone asked Shultz he could laugh his lack of knowledge off and claim he relied on Django for all of that and just handled the money himself.